# Correct usage of only

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

I read this rule somewhere:

> **Only** can be used before a verb though it may put emphasis on a noun used later in the sentence

Is it true? For example, is this sentence correct?

> Although he **only** earns eight hundred rupees a month, he manages to support his family adequately.

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be "he earns **only 800 rupees**" because **only** refers to the amount - but your version is perfectly acceptable and would not be misunderstood.

Comment: That rule is correct, so your sentence is correct.